# CocoaPods 'auto property synthesis' error in installed library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

[image]

The project I am working in is a Swift project. I needed to import a Objective C library and installation was only available (advertised) through 'CocoaPods'. I proceeded and installed the required library and built a bridging header.

Now for some reason I have a single random error deep in one of the files in the library. I'm 99% sure this is a problem with my set up as I can't find anyone else using Braintree (a rather popular payment service by PayPal) with the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a consequence of overriding NSObject's `description` whose definition changed in iOS 8. (See http://www.redwindsoftware.com/blog/post/2014/08/20/NSObject-has-some-new-properties-in-iOS-8.aspx). Is there a more recent release of this library available for you to use?